# How separate and compare the strings from a txt file

Tags: android, string, compare

I need your help!

I have any informations mixed in a txt file:

I have to assign a score according to the rules below

- 2 points for correct answer;

  -1 point for incorrect answer;

  points for question not answered (with space)

and classify the total points according to the grade below

- 40~36 =>> A

  35~31 =>> B

  30~26 =>> C

My code is:

```
    private void readRaw() {
        tv.append("\n\nDiretório do arquivo processado: res/raw/history_data.txt:\n");
        InputStream is = this.getResources()
                .openRawResource(R.raw.history_data);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr, 8192);


        try {
            String test;


            while (true) {
                test = br.readLine();


    // How do I compare the contents of the first line with the contents of the last 20                                     characters of each line?

                if (test == null)
                    break;
                else
                tv.append("\n" + "    " + test);

            }

            isr.close();
            is.close();
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
private void readRaw() {
        tv.append("\n\nDiretório do arquivo processado: res/raw/history_data.txt:\n");
        InputStream is = this.getResources()
                .openRawResource(R.raw.history_data);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr, 8192);

        try {
            String test, correctAnswer = null;
            int lineNo = 0;

            ArrayList<String> studentNames = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<String>(); 

            while (true) {
                test = br.readLine();
                if (test == null)
                    break;
                else
                    tv.append("\n" + "    " + test);

                if(lineNo == 0)
                {
                    correctAnswer = test;
                }
                else
                {
                    String[] contents = test.split(" ", 2);
                    studentNames.add(contents[0]);
                    answers.add(contents[1]);
                }
                lineNo++;
            }

            for (String string : answers) {
                int result = compare(string, correctAnswer);
                // get grade according to points and print the information
            }

            isr.close();
            is.close();
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Use the `compare()` function to compare the student's answers to the actual answer

```
    private int compare(String string, String correctAnswer) {

        int totalPoints = 0;
        if(string.length() != correctAnswer.length())
        {
            return totalPoints;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            if(string.charAt(i) == correctAnswer.charAt(i) && string.charAt(i) != ' ')
            {
                totalPoints += 2;
            }
            else if(string.charAt(i) != ' ')
            {
                totalPoints -= 1;
            }
        }
        return totalPoints;
    }
```

Comment: You're welcome. I've left the printing part for you :)
Just iterate over the `ArrayList`s and get each element to print.

Comment: anyway, helped me a lot, thank you very much my friend, big hug.

Comment: Where did you want to print?